# RDS server error

Tags: apache-flex, struts, blazeds

When I connect data services using blazeds I get following error message.

```
  RDS server message
  Premature EOF encountered
```

Why am not able to connect?

But when specify remoteObject in the declaration tags and call the methods it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know the exact reason but this problem occurred when i was using Adobe Flash Builder Burrito. then i changed to Adobe Flash Builder Premium where it worked fine.